# How can collapsible elements (QMenu, QComboBox) be rendered to a bitmap buffer with Qt?

Tags: python, c++, qt, bitmap

In Qt there are various methods to render QWidgets to a bitmap buffer (for example a QImage)
These methods can be:

```
QWidget.render(QPainter, ...)
QWidget.grab()
QPixmap::grabWidget(QWidget)
QPixmap::grabWindow( ID )
```

There are lots of variants possible. However, none of them seems to render collapsible elements like (Sub-)Menus or Comboboxes.

Also I found a bugreport in Qt that might be related to it
[QTBUG-10683](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-10683) (if this a bug at all)

So, how can elements like an expanded QComboBox or QMenu be rendered to a QImage or any other Bitmap form like Byte-Array. It should work for rendering invisible off-screen content, so capturing the current desktop via OS is not an option. I am happy for all hints, don't care whether it's C++, Python or just words explaining what is happening here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the problem here: popups are standalone windows.

You can iterate children and capture all the child Windows. Then blend them to final image or just put in list.

To find if widget is standalone window you can use [isWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#isWindow) function.

To capture hidden UI elements you can use qt meta-system:

```
void captureHiddenItems(QWidget* widget, QList<QImage>& list) {
  if(auto* comboBox = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(widget)) {
    comboBox->showPopup();
    captureChildWindows(comboBox, list);
    comboBox->hidePopup();
  } else if(auto* menubar  = qobject_cast<QMenuBar*>(widget) ) {
    capturePopUpMenus(menubar->actions(), list);
  }
}

void capturePopUpMenus(QList<QAction*> actions, QList<QImage>& list) {
  for(auto* action : actions) {
    if(auto* menu = action->menu()) {
      captureWidget(menu, list);
      capturePopUpMenus(menu->actions(), list);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help so far - any idea how to determine the correct relative rendering position of the child windows? 'Parent position plus parent height' works for QComboBox, but I guess there is a more elegant way working in QMenuBar submenus also?